# Search results to display category names

Tags: search, php, categories

I need to work out how to incorporate category names into the search results url.

I found a solution using php (noted below) which adds the relevant category names into the appropriate position in the url. This works perfectly well, however i need to alter this code so that it accepts multiple category names. Currently it inserts the category names associated with 'beauty', but I also need it do do the same thing for 'hair', 'nails' etc..

I am no php expert so any help is appreciated!

```
{exp:search:search_results}

<?php $autoPath = '{auto_path}';
$lastSegment = basename($autoPath);

//Beauty URL update, based on the category assigned to the entry

if(strpos($autoPath, 'beauty')){

//variable to assign the category to the appropriate URL segment for the Rule

$catVar = 1;
$basename = 'catPath';

?>

{categories}
 <?php
 $tempname = $basename.$catVar;
 $$tempname = "{category_url_title}";
 $catVar++;
 ?>
{/categories}

<?php $autoPath = "http://www.mysite.com/products/"."beauty/$catPath1/$lastSegment";
} ?>

<h3><a href="<?php echo $autoPath; ?>" title="{title}">{title}</a></h3>
<p>{excerpt}</p>
{paginate}<p>{pagination_links}</p>{/paginate}

{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Comment: why did you go the php route?

Comment: The other way i found was to purchase a pricey add-on. As there some easier way?

Comment: yeah you're probably right about that, low search is really nice though and I really hate running php in any of my templates. I would think some MySQL statements would be better but not sure how to get you started with that.